# What algorithm can perform string pattern search JS?

Tags: javascript, full-text-search

In the frontend there is a list of game titles that consist of strings:

id, game name, date, price
The search shall accept multiple keywords, e.g. user might type: `1998 Streetfighter 2` or `Streetfighter 1998` Currently I create an array separated by empty space, that creates 3 keywords: `[1998, Streetfighter , 2 ]` Then I go through the collection of game titles to filter matches. unfortunately it also gives back any title that includes "2" because there is no pattern recognition that identifies "Streetfighter 2" belongs together. Is there a simple algorithm to provide a pattern search?

```
const allGames = [
"Streetfighter 1, 1992, 20",
"Streetfighter 2, 1998, 20",
"pokemon, 2016, 20",
"Diablo 3, 2015, 40",
"Super mario, 1995, 20",
"The Witcher, 2012, 20",
]
```

Comment: Note that Super Mario was released in 1985, not 1995

Comment: `because there is no pattern recognition that identifies "Streetfighter 2" belongs together` So are you saying you only want to match the whole string and not just parts of it?

Comment: use array of objects,so that you have particular keys you can traverse ,match or filter out.something like 

const allGames=[{name:"Streetfighter 2",releaseDate:"20-12-1992"}]
for release date use Date object,i recommend,so that if you have thousands of games ,you can filter one using unique release date or name

Answer (score 1):

Your search query looks advanced enough to justify using a search engine. Just don't create one yourself (it's harder than you may think).

In this answer I'll be using [Lunr.js](https://lunrjs.com/)

Here's a 2min crash course:

1. Transform your data into documents. *(I've already converted your initial `allGames` array.)*
2. Then create a search index where you:

   1. Specify which property of a document holds a unique identifier. *(In our case `title`.)*
   2. Define which properties should be indexed. *(In our case all of them.)*
   3. Define a boost score for each property. *(i.e a match in the title has a higher relevance score than a match in the price.)*
3. Add all documents to the search index.
4. Search! ;)

---

**Search Query FTW!**

Notice the last search, I'm using a wildcard in the search string (`street*`) to find the two Street Fighter titles!

---

```js
const createLunrIndex = docs =>
  lunr(function () {
    this.ref('title');
    this.field('title', 5);
    this.field('date', 3);
    this.field('price', 1);
    for (doc of docs) this.add(doc);
  });

const search = (lunrIndex, term) =>
  lunrIndex
    .search(term)
    .map(res => res.ref)
    
const gamesIndex = createLunrIndex(allGames);

console.log(
  search(gamesIndex, '1998 Streetfighter 2')
);

console.log(
  search(gamesIndex, 'Streetfighter 1998')
);

console.log(
  search(gamesIndex, 'street*')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lunr/lunr.js"></script>
<script>
const allGames =
  [ { "title": "Streetfighter 1"
    , "date": "1992"
    , "price": "20"
    }
    ,
    { "title": "Streetfighter 2"
    , "date": "1998"
    , "price": "20"
    }
    ,
    { "title": "pokemon"
    , "date": "2016"
    , "price": "20"
    }
    ,
    { "title": "Diablo 3"
    , "date": "2015"
    , "price": "40"
    }
    ,
    { "title": "Super mario"
    , "date": "1985"
    , "price": "20"
    }
    ,
    { "title": "The Witcher"
    , "date": "2012"
    , "price": "20"
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: hey thank you very much. I still don't know how I can create the index with lunar for  react js. Do you know? [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lunr)